# Windows Batch: Why are spaces being inserted after my file path?

Tags: windows, batch-file

I've an infuriating problem. I want to call a batch from within my batch. I'm setting the path to the batch in SCRIPT_DIR and calling the batch within a for loop. Problem is, for some reason, three spaces are being inserted at the end of the path stored in SCRIPT_DIR so instead of

```
V:\bin\EP4BIN\SCRIPTS\Myfilewapper.bat
```

I get-

```
V:\bin\EP4BIN\SCRIPTS\              Myfilewapper.bat
```

and the call fails because the file cannot be found.

Anyone know why these extra spaces are being inserted?

```
@echo off

SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
SET VEDT_BASE_DIR=%~d0
SET SCRIPT_DIR=%VEDT_BASE_DIR%\BIN\USER\SCRIPTS\    

for /f %%a in ('dir /b e:\xxx\batchfacility\inc*trans') do (
    CALL !SCRIPT_DIR!Myfile_wrapper.bat Inc%%aTrans 00000020 
    pause
```

......

Answer (score 2):

You have trailing spaces in your script:

```
SET SCRIPT_DIR=%VEDT_BASE_DIR%\BIN\USER\SCRIPTS\    
                                                ^^^^
```

Comment: So I did. Duh! Thought it was something more complicated. Thanks!

Comment: you can easily avoid this type of error if you use this syntax: `set "var=value"`

Answer (score 0):

Try expanding var %%a and replace all spaces with nothing ..

Set var=%%a

Set "var=!var: =!"